# Проблема с циклом While и постоянной проверкой условия

Tags: c#

Имею след. цикл:

```
while (isReady == false)
            {
                if (Clipboard.ContainsText() == true)
                {
                    textCopy = Clipboard.GetText();

                    isReady = linkChecking(out readyText, textCopy);
                }
            }
```

Мне нужно чтобы он работал всегда, пока не найдёт то, что мне нужно. Он так и делает, но когда находит в буфере обмена текст, он немного зависает, а потом выдаёт результат (верный). Но мне нужно, чтобы он работал без прерываний, подзависаний.

Я проверял без цикла, он сразу за меньше секунды делал то, что нужно. Следовательно это из-за цикла.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте заменить цикл таймером. Хотя без описания что и зачем вы делаете сложно что то посоветовать.

Comment: Можно из среды исполнения прервать отладку и посмотреть - а где оно висит, собственно, в каком месте программы. А вообще скорее всего как обычно GUI не получает управление из-за крутящегося цикла, например.

Comment: Вам нужно следить за изменениями в буфере обмена, так? И выполнять какое-то действие, когда там будет нужный текст, так? Winforms это у вас или WPF?

Comment: Если, что крутить в цикле читалку буфера обмена - это ошибка. Есть вполне валидный мониторинг буфера обмена, который будет вызывать вам код как только в буфере обмена что-то поменяется. У меня даже есть код такого класса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Clipboard` не подходит для ваших целей, т. к. `Clipboard.GetText` *обязан* выполняться в UI потоке, а создавать бесконечный цикл в UI потоке... ну такое. Метод решения тут 1: создать свой `Clipboard`-подобный класс:

```
static SharedDataManager
{
    static readonly object syncRoot = new object();
    static string? text;

    public string? Text
    {
        get { lock (syncRoot) { return text; } }
        set { lock (syncRoot) { text = value; } }
    }
}
```

```
async ValueTask<string> GetTextAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => { });

    string coercedText;
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        var text = SharedDataManager.Text;

        if (text != null && // аналог `Clipboard.ContainsText()`
            TryCoerceText(text, out coercedText)) // аналог `lineChecking`
            break;
    }

    stopwatch.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show($"{coercedText} at {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds - 1000} ms");

    return coercedText;
}
async ValueTask SetTextAsync(string text)
{
    await Task.Run(() => { });

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    SharedTextManager.Text = text;
}
void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    // не ожидаем задачи в UI потоке – нам не важен результат
    _ = GetTextAsync();       // чтоб заткнуть компилятор
    _ = SetTextAsync(<text>); //
}
```

Вывод в msgbox:

```
<coerced text> at <1-10> ms
```

---

Проблема не в цикле, а в том, что вы его создали в UI потоке.

Comment: `Метод решения тут 1` а как же мониторинг буфера обмена? Win 32 API `SetClipboardViewer`, вот это вот всё? :(

Comment: @aepot ну идём мы нафиг с буфером обмена. не я придумал, что `Clipboard` *обязан* работать в UI потоке. думал, как бы выполнить операцию за пределами UI потока, но с использованием UI фичей – ничего не надумал. да и спрашивающему, думаю, этого было достаточно

Comment: Ну тогда я в шоке и не понял, спрашивающий, как по мне, писал про то, как ему буфер обмена трекать, а вы ему про асинхронность ответили. И самое интересное - он принял ответ. Это можно решить без асинхронности, просто прикрутив коллбэк к событию изменения буфера обмена, которое винда радостно закинет в Message Loop окна, если ее вежливо об этом попросить.

Comment: @aepot значит он хотел это делать через асинхронность. ну, хотя через "событие" тут, конечно, проще. хотя, если функции трека clipboard'а нет в WPF (без учёта Win API), то тут уже надо смотреть, что проще: `DllImport` или `async`

Comment: @aepot у вас, наверно, уже есть готовый код для монитора. можете его прикрутить в свой ответ

Comment: А теперь представьте приложение, которое 100500 раз в секунду читает с помощью предложенной вами асинхронности буфер обмена. Я бы уже давно дал ответ, но я не знаю, WPF это или Winforms, в них Message Loop по-разному перехватывается.

Comment: @aepot дайте ему абстракцию "мы можем дать в `WndProc` калл-бэк" и опишите её реализацию 2-я способами: через WinForms и через WPF. Затем создайте оболочку вокруг этой абстракции, чтоб проще было использовать. вот и всё! «Основные принципы структурирования в случае ООП...: 1. Абстракция» – [*Wikipedia*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Я лучше подожду, когда он вернется на SO и скажет, что у него ничего не получается, там и поговрим. Хотя в теории может получиться, скажем через `Thread.Sleep(1000)`. Тогда хоть и с задержкой, но можно будет читать буфер в асинхронном цикле, и видеть изменения. Там еще будет периодически `Clipboard is busy` и прочие прелести синхронизации. Подождем.

Comment: @aepot ок. просто ок